# What is the plastic and cloth part around the shifter called?

Tags: part-identification

What is this part pictured below called? It is a roughly rectangular piece of plastic located in the center console, with a cutout containing a cloth or leather hood that covers the shifter lever itself.

[image]

This picture is from a 2000 Audi A4 B5, 1.9 TDI.

Comment: Year, Make, Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normally called something close to the "Audi A4 shifter trim."  If you google for relevant images, you see a whole variety of pieces that look like your outline.  Here is an example (from [this vendor's site](http://audis4parts.com/interior-parts/00-01-02-audi-a4-s4-oem-shifter-trim-boot-leather/)):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The hard plastic pieces are generally referred to a the console. The soft part that surrounds the shifter is called the boot.